# Get email body by python 3.4

Tags: email, python-3.4

I want get email body. My email is html and save in *part*. Use this code:

```
print('charset =', part.get_content_charset())
html = part.get_payload(decode=True)
print ('type =', type(html))
print('text =', html)
```

result is:

```
charset = utf-8
type = <class 'bytes'>
text = b'...<font face="DejaVu Sans Mono">\\u044d\\u0442\\u043e html<br>\n...
```

I want have normal text, but no \u044d\u0442\u043e.

Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a byte array. You have to decode the bytes to a string:

```
text.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: this no work, result = `<font face="DejaVu Sans Mono">\\u044d\\u0442\\u043e html<br>\n`